# Atualizar valor bool em uma coluna jsonb - jsonb_set

Tags: sql, postgresql, query, jsonb

Tenho o seguinte json de exemplo:

```
{
  "red": false,
  "blue": false,
  "yellow": false
}
```

Preciso atualizar um deles para true e o resultado que eu espero é:

```
{
  "red": false,
  "blue": false,
  "yellow": true
}
```

Primeiro tentei atualizar assim:

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET jsonb_column_name = jsonb_set(jsonb_column_name, '{yellow}', ('"true"')::jsonb, true)
```

Mas meu resultado foi:

```
{
  "red": false,
  "blue": false,
  "yellow": "true"
}
```

e não é isso que eu quero, uma string no lugar do bool

Tentei também:

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET jsonb_column_name = jsonb_set(jsonb_column_name, '{yellow}', true, true)
```

Mas meu resultado é um erro, que faz sentido por que o 3o parametro precisa ser do tipo jsonb:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, boolean, boolean) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Mas também não posso fazer true::jsonb por que não da pra converter bool pra jsonb:

```
SQL Error [42846]: ERROR: cannot cast type boolean to jsonb
```

Existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso? não precisa ser com jsonb_set, uso ela por que nos outros casos do meu sistema tem funcionado bem